# Screen slide height

Tags: html, css

So I have made a web page using html and css, and it consists of four slides. The menu is at the top(header) and clicking on each element shows that slide.

Each slide has a video background.

Each slide has it's content made by divs( one left, one right and so on), the divs having text or images. The content scrolls and the video stays fixed.

All works pretty well, but my main problem is that the height of each slide is determined by the height of the slide that has the longest content. And so, 3 of my 4 slides have a blank space at their end.

This is my html document's body :

```css
  html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.wrap {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  -ms-overflow-style: none;
  overflow: scroll;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  background: #120103;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
}

header {
  background: #060523;
  box-shadow: 0 .5em 1em #111;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 900;
  width: 100%;
  opacity: 0.9;
}

header label {
  color: #788188;
  cursor: default;
  display: inline-block;
  line-height: 4.25em;
  font-size: .667em;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 0 1em;
}

header label:hover {
  background: #0b0a3f;
  height: inherit;
}

.slide {
  height: 200%;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 100%;
  z-index: 20;
  padding: 0;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-color: #120103;
  background-position: 50% 50%;
  background-size: cover;
  transition: left 0s .75s;
}

.vidwrap {
  position: fixed;
}

#video_bg_elem {
  position: absolute;
  height: 900px;
  width: 1440px;
}

.content {
  position: absolute;
  min-width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  z-index: 1000;
  background-color: transparent;
  opacity: 0.4;
}

.div1 {
  margin-left: 15px;
  float: left;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  width: 49%;
  height: auto;
  display: inline-block;
}

.div2 {
  float: right;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  width: 49%;
  height: auto;
  display: inline-block;
}

img {
  border: 1px solid white;
  display: inline;
  vertical-align: top;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.slide-one {
  height: auto;
}

.slide-two {
  height: auto;
}

.slide-three {
  height: auto;
}

.slide-four {
  height: auto;
}

[id^="slide"]:checked+.slide {
  left: 0;
  z-index: 100;
  transition: left .65s ease-out;
}

.slide h1 {
  opacity: 0;
  transform: translateY(100%);
  transition: transform .5s .5s, opacity .5s;
}

[id^="slide"]:checked+.slide h1 {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: translateY(0);
  transition: all .5s .5s;
}

.slide p {
  opacity: 0;
  transform: translateY(100%);
  transition: transform .5s .5s, opacity .5s;
}

[id^="slide"]:checked+.slide p {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: translateY(0);
  transition: all .5s .5s;
  .slide img {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translateY(100%);
    transition: transform .5s .5s, opacity .5s;
  }
  [id^="slide"]:checked+.slide p {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translateY(0);
    transition: all .5s .5s;
  }
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <header>
    <label for="slide-1-trigger">1</label>
    <label for="slide-2-trigger">2</label>
    <label for="slide-3-trigger">3</label>
    <label for="slide-4-trigger">4</label>
  </header>
  <input id="slide-1-trigger" type="radio" name="slides" style="display:none;" checked>
  <section class="slide slide-one">
    <div class="vidwrap">
      <video id="video_bg_elem" preload="auto" autoplay="true" loop="loop" muted="muted">
                            <source src="vid/1.mp4">
                            </video>
    </div>
    <br>
    <h1>Title 1</h1>
    <div>
      <div class="div1">
        <p>Text</p>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
      </div>
      <div class="div2">
        <br>
        <br>
        <p><img src="Images/1.jpg" width="512" height="320"></p>
        <br>
        <br>
      </div>
      <div class="div1">
        <p>Text</p>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
      </div>
      <div class="div2">
        <p><img src="Images/2.jpg" width="320" height="320"></p>
      </div>
      <div class="div1">
        <p>Text</p>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
      </div>
      <div class="div2">
        <br>
        <br>
        <p><img src="Images/3.jpg" width="320" height="320"></p>
        <br>
        <br>
      </div>
      <div class="div1">
        <p>Text</p>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
      </div>
      <div class="div2">
        <br>
        <br>
        <p><img src="Images/4.jpg" width="320" height="320"></p>
        <br>
        <br>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
  <input id="slide-2-trigger" type="radio" name="slides" style="display:none;">
  <section class="slide slide-two">
    <div class="vidwrap">
      <video id="video_bg_elem" preload="auto" autoplay="true" loop="loop" muted="muted">
                            <source src="vid/2.mp4">
                            </video>
    </div>
    <br>
    <br>
    <h1>Title</h1>
    <div>
      <div class="div1">Left Text</div>
      <div class="div2">Right Text</div>
    </div>
  </section>
  <input id="slide-3-trigger" type="radio" name="slides" style="display:none;">
  <section class="slide slide-three">
    <div class="vidwrap">
      <video id="video_bg_elem" preload="auto" autoplay="true" loop="loop" muted="muted">
                            <source src="vid/3.mp4">
                            </video>
    </div>
    <h1>Title</h1>
  </section>
  <input id="slide-4-trigger" type="radio" name="slides" style="display:none;">
  <section class="slide slide-four">
    <div class="vidwrap">
      <video id="video_bg_elem" preload="auto" autoplay="true" loop="loop" muted="muted">
                            <source src="vid/4.mp4">
                            </video>
    </div>

  </section>
```

What shoud i modify in order to have on each slide a specific height, not the height of the longest slide?
I've tried with height:auto but it didn't work.

Comment: You need to give it a fixed height then, as simple as that.

Comment: Thanks, i solved the problem by setting a fixed height and setting the overflow for slide to scroll.